# Binding Telerik MVC Combobox to a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, combobox, telerik-mvc

My application is asp.net MVC, trying to bind a Telerik MVC Combobox to a model.
Here is the model:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool DisplayBold { get; set; }
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0}|{1}", this.Id, this.DisplayBold.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

In the controller:

```
  var people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", DisplayBold = true });
        people.Add(new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Jayne Doe", DisplayBold = false });
        ViewData["people"] = people;
        return View();
```

I do get the values.

In the view:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
       .Name("ComboBox")
           .BindTo((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["people"])
%>
```

I get the follwing error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[caseprog.Models.Person]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.
```

I would appreciate your suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just cast a List of People to a `IEnumerable` of `SelectListItem`.  They're two different things.

Instead, you need to convert the list to a list of `SelectListItem`.  You can do that in a number of ways, but this one should work:

```
.BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable<Person>)ViewData["people"], "Id", "Name"))
```

Comment: Thank you, I got this error: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.SelectList(System.Collections.IEnumerable, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @user373721 you need to cast the ViewData to a IEnumerable<Person>

Comment: Thank you, sorry but I am not that experienced.  I added  .BindTo(new SelectList(IEnumerable < Person > ViewData["people"], "Id", "Name")).  then got this error: 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: @user373721 - you are not using the casting syntax.  (IEnumerable<Person>)

Comment: I would appreciate if you can tell me how to use the casting syntax.  Thanks